# find outdated .NET Core Global Tools

Tags: .net-core

I wonder, whether there is a tool which could inform about the possible updates of currently installed  .NET Core Global Tools - something cute like `npm -g outdated` in the "nodejs" world :) ?

For more detail to explain what I mean:

`dotnet tool list -g`
gets the list of the globally installed packages.

`dotnet tool update -g <package-name>`

does uninstall the package and install it again with the latest version according to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-tools). (note the `-g` option refers to the globally installed packages, locally installed packages are meant without the `-g`)

The most close solution, I have found so far, is based on the [dotnet-search](https://github.com/billpratt/dotnet-search), which has its cons
 - list in a table format often several packages corresponding to the search pattern of one particular  package name and has other cons.
 - table format, (not solved pull request with e.g. Json format) ...

Does by chance someone else developed similar own cli tool for that? Or is it  planned any enhancements in the dotnet tool command in the near future to cover this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created .NET global tool for it. Perhaps it could be helpful for the others as well...

NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-tools-outdated

source code (with more info) : https://github.com/rychlym/dotnet-tools-outdated